# Find something in column A then show the value of B for that row in excel

Tags: excel

I have column A, B, C - I want to search value from column B in column A and display adjacent cell value of C.

So far i could able to find the value - But don't know how to display the adject cell value of C

```
=(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B4, $A$4:$A$341, 1, FALSE)), FALSE, TRUE))
```

Can anyone help me with formula?

Comment: Could you add example of data and desired output?

Comment: I really don't know how to draw the cell in here - But i will try to explain - Column B has values apple,mango,pineapple , Column A has values Apple,mango,pineapple,strawbery, Column has values fruits,vegetables etc., 

I want to find value of Column B Apple in Column A and display corresponding value of Column C

Comment: Try this https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Answer (score 1):

Just use the VLOOKUP to return the Value:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,$A$4:$C$341, 3, FALSE)
```

If you want to deal with the fact that it may not be found you can wrap in IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,$A$4:$C$341, 3, FALSE),"Not Found")
```